# Font Awesome Stick Notes not showing

Tags: font-awesome

I am using Font Awesome.  If I use various icons, like the calendar or the speech bubble, they all work.
However this one appears not to work anymore.

If I change it to the calendar or others, they show.  When I change it to this one, it fails.  Any ideas?

Comment: Post the HTML you're using and the version of font-awesome you have

Comment: Apologies.  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href='/member/$row->memberid&u=addnote'><i class='fa fa-comment-o'></i> Add Note</a>
      <a href='/member/$row->memberid&u=addnote'><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i> Add Attend date</a>

This is what works.  but if I use : <i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o"></i>
it won't show.  Even with <i class='fa fa-sticky-note-o'></i>.

Comment: @Simon_a6 - it would be clearer to add the code into the original question

Comment: Bingo - something you said highlighted that there are "versions" of the CSS.  I noticed on their web site they state the v 4.4, and I was using an old version.

Answer (score 3):

Your library is too old, change version to at least 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

This Problem is due to the **updation** on font-awesome file.Update your font-awesome .

Answer (score 0):

The sticky note options (`fa-sticky-note` and `fa-sticky-note-o`) were added in Font Awesome 4.4.  Once you update your Font-Awesome files, those glyphs will properly render for you.